# Different URLs for the same node

Tags: nodes, theming

I want to have make a node accessible via 2 different url. I want to apply a different theme on every one of theme.
They will be event/id and app/event/id. There will also be a third alias via pathauto but this will just be the same with event/id.

Any idea on a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried using hook menu to create both path? Another issue to be fully aware of is that having multiple URLs providing the same content could very well hurt your SEO. Is 301 redirect not good enough for the use case?

Comment: @rwaery Core adds a canonical tag to nodes by default, from an SEO point of view there's no danger doing this.

Comment: Sounds about right :)

Comment: @Clive Thanks for the informative input. And looking at your rep points, you know your stuff. I just remembered reading it somewhere that duplicated pages should be addressed appropriately. And isn't that exactly what the module global redirect trying to solve? [https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect]

Comment: Absolutely @rwaery, duplicate pages should definitely be addressed as they can negatively impact your ranking...but a meta canonical tag is actually the preferred way of addressing this problem, provided you actually want the same content on two different URLs. A 301 is great if you want to redirect the user, but for "content available through multiple URL structures", the big G actually [recommend this method themselves](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Comment: @Clive wow, resourceful as always! This is my first time seeing that attribute rel='canonical'. And I have always thought robots.txt or .htaccess were my only helpers with SEO. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, @Clive When you said 'Core ads a canonical tag to nodes by default' does that mean by default the node/%nid is the preferred path? what happened when you set an alias using pathauto and such or adding another path with canonical tag?

Comment: @rwaery No the current alias (read: whatever comes back from `entity_uri()` at that point) is the preferred path for canonical. The 'shortlink' is (by default) node/%nid, though. The magic happens in [`node_page_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_page_view/7) if you're interested.

Comment: @Clive, that helps. But what about if the path isn't a node or entity page? Like, If I was using render API and my own hook menu, do I need to add the canonical meta tag on my own?

Comment: @rwaery Yes you'd have to add your own tags for custom page types